# DAX function for DirectQuery in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to use DAX functions (e.g. SELECTCOLUMNS(), FILTER()) for Row Level Security in PowerBI but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-function-dax did mention that those functions are not supported for use in DirectQuery mode when used in calculated columns or row-level security (RLS) rules. Any solution on this problem because my data source is currently connect with DirectQuery mode. Thank you.

Comment: there is no way to use those function other than change your connection to import mode. but if you provide an example of what you are trying achieve. describing: your input data and the expected outcome. there maybe a way around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to create a reference table of the DirectQuery dataset and enforce the same row-level security? This way the data is separate from the DirectQuery limitations.

Comment: Hi @OBro, it seems like a good idea. I would like to discuss this idea with my colleagues Thanks man.